# How do I toggle the relay?

Tags: python, toggle

I need a program to control lights for a garden and I am having a hard time finishing.  I just need a toggle command because right now the relay only turns on for the exact time set and not the entire time.

```
try:
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now().time()
    GPIO.output(R1,GPIO.LOW)
    if now.hour == 7 and now.minute == 0 and now.second == 1:
        #need toggle command
        GPIO.output(R1, GPIO.HIGH)
    elif now.hour == 23 and now.minute == 0 and now.second == 1:
        #need toggle command
        GPIO.output(R1, GPIO.LOW)
    
finally:
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Toggling a pin usually works by

1. reading the current state
2. inverting the read state
3. writing the inverted value

Code for a toggle function:

```py
def toggle_gpio(pin_id):
    current_state = GPIO.input(pin_id)
    new_state = GPIO.LOW if current_state == GPIO.HIGH else GPIO.LOW
    GPIO.output(pin_id, new_state)
```

But I would advise against the toggle approach since you have to make sure that it only is executed once per second (otherwise your pin toggles back and forth for a second).

Instead write a method that calculates the desired state at each point (e.g. if after turn on time but before turn off time -> on, otherwise off) and then set that desired state to the output pin.